# API Automation: Receiving Output like "`io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath@12345xxx " on "GET" request

Tags: json, api, rest-assured

I am new to REST assured and API Automation, I have tried the following code using "GET" request:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "{Url}";
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()
                                       .contentType("x-www-form-urlencoded")
                                       .formParam("grant_type", "")
                                       .formParam("client_id", "") 
                                       .formParam("scope", "")
                                       .formParam("client_secret","");
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);
    JsonPath res = response.jsonPath();
    //String BearerToken = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println("The response is:" +res);
    int code = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("The status code is" +code);
    assertEquals(code, 200);
  } 
}
```

and I get the following output

> io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath@12345xxx

This isn't right as I need to receive a proper JSON as a response.
Please Note: I have hidden some of the values pertaining to security risk.

Can someone please help me to resolve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print response from the Rest Assured you can use `asString()` method on `Response` object. You don't need to use JsonPath to print the results:

```
Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);
System.out.println("The response is:" + response.asString());
```

OR you can use JsonPath's `prettyPrint()` method:

```
Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);
JsonPath res = response.jsonPath();
res.prettyPrint(); //no need to call System.out.println
```

Comment: Tried the second option which is by using "prettyprint" and got the below exception:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
 at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 2, column: 1, while reading '<', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!! and please help me to get through this

Comment: @user3836459 Can you start a new question, provide the JSON you receive from the API and put the link in here so we can start a new topic?

Comment: Yes done, Please check the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578133/exception-in-thread-main-io-restassured-path-json-exception-jsonpathexception