# Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document while trying to "automate an API "

Tags: json, api, automation

I am getting the following exception while trying to Automate an API:
Exception in thread "main" io.restassured.path.json.exception.JsonPathException: Failed to parse the JSON document
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1002)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4.doParseWith(JsonPath.java:967)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$JsonParser.parseWith(JsonPath.java:1047)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.toJsonString(JsonPath.java:1064)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.prettify(JsonPath.java:685)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.prettyPrint(JsonPath.java:700)
at ApiAutomation_BDD.ApiAutomation_BDD.bearerToken_GETRequest.main(bearerToken_GETRequest.java:35)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 2, column: 1, while reading '<', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:86)
at groovy.json.JsonLexer$nextToken.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parse(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:97)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper$parse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
at io.restassured.internal.path.json.ConfigurableJsonSlurper.parseText(ConfigurableJsonSlurper.groovy:83)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$4$1.method(JsonPath.java:965)
at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath$ExceptionCatcher.invoke(JsonPath.java:1000)
... 6 more

and the following is the code which I tried (again not sharing any values coz of security risk):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  {
RestAssured.baseURI = "{Url}";
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()
                                   .contentType("x-www-form-urlencoded")
                                   .formParam("grant_type", "")
                                   .formParam("client_id", "") 
                                   .formParam("scope", "")
                                   .formParam("client_secret","");
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET);
    JsonPath res = response.jsonPath();
    //String BearerToken = response.getBody().asString();
    //System.out.println("The response is:" +res);
    res.prettyPrint();
    int code = response.getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("The status code is" + code);
    assertEquals(code, 200);
```

}
}

Comment: Looks like the response is empty or it's not in JSON format. Try to do the same with Postman

Comment: yes I am getting a valid Json format as output using postman

Comment: You need to verify if you send your request to correct URL. Also, move status assertion before you try to print the JSON to make sure you got HTTP 200

Comment: The problem I receive is : I am getting a response code as 200 and a bunch of lines written in "Javascript" as "Response" where the actual response should be in "Json"

Comment: I have no idea for now. Can you edit your question and add that response?